# JavaScript regex for string literal?

Tags: javascript, regex, literals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a RegExp.escape function in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript)

I'm currently using: `var keywords = new RegExp(req.params.keywords, 'i');`

The catch is, if `req.params.keywords == '.*'`, this will match anything, what I want is for it to match `.*` literally, as in `\.\*\`

Is there a more elegant solution than escaping every passed single character with a `\`?

Comment: In the process of showing what you mean, you almost solved your own problem. Just remove that last `backslash (\)` and you are done.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to match literally, instead of using the regular expressions included in the string, don't use a regular expression. Use the string `indexOf()` function to see if a string is contained withing another one.

For case insensitive matching, you convert each string to, say, lower case before the match.

```
var searchForString = req.params.keywords.toLowerCase();
var searchInString = xxx.toLowerCase();
if (searchInString.indexOf(searchForString) >= 0) {
    ... then it matches ...
}
```

Comment: this is for querying MongoDB, which requires a `RegExp` for `LIKE` operations

Comment: Then you have to put in the backslashes on certain characters.